# Grunt connect proxy, handle subdomain handling

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I have rails app which located on **127.0.0.1:8080** . 
Also I have domain **app.dev** wrote in my host file

```
app.dev     127.0.0.1
my.app.dev  127.0.0.1
```

I want to configure grunt as follows:

- All requests to **app.dev** redirect to rails app **127.0.0.1:8080**
- All requests to **my.app.dev** handle connect server

Is it possible to do by **grunt** and **grunt-connect-proxy** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP Proxy using Connect and node-http-proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723668/http-proxy-using-connect-and-node-http-proxy)